# Execute Data Factory pipeline based on event in table

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a requirement to trigger Azure Data Factory pipeline whenever there is a new record in a table. Is there any way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

No, [Event-based trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipeline-execution-triggers) only support Azure Blob Storage by now.
You can vote [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/39508147-df-event-trigger-on-update-or-insert-within-azur) to progress this feature in Azure Data Factory.

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is not possible.
There is a similar discussion going on in the below thread :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/197465/how-to-trigger-an-adf-based-on-any-data-changes-wi.html

Answer (score 0):

While this is not currently supported, here's an idea on how to fake it. (Just sharing an idea, not sure whether this is feasible.)

1. Create a Trigger on INSERT
2. Trigger executes a Stored Procedure
3. Stored Procedure uses Polybase to create text file in Blob Storage with the relevant information (like new row ID).
4. Create a BlobCreated event trigger over that Storage location in ADF or Logic App.

Doing this should end up with an Event Trigger that fires whenever a new row is inserted.

Comment: I think you're mixing and matching a few things there @JoelCochran, so I'm not sure that would work.  Azure SQL DB does support triggers but not Polybase.  OP mentioned Azure SQL DB on linked discussion.  Azure Synapse Analytics (dedicated SQL pool) does support Polybase, not triggers.  IaaS / SQL on a VM supports both (I think) but OP hasn't mentioned that.  See what I mean?  I did think Logic App firing ADF pipeline would work but haven't tested it.  Interesting problem, but could always be faked by regular polling, eg every 15 mins.

Comment: Thanks @wBob, I was mostly just thinking out loud, trying to come up with an idea. I think you're correct that Polling is probably the way to go, we do that in our internal Pipeline Management system: a Logic App fires every few minutes and calls a Stored Procedure to check whether there are any rows in a table to process.

Answer (score 0):

We can use logic app to trigger a pipeline based on a query that finds data inserted in past x minutes/seconds

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct way to do this in  ADF (yet). As others have pointed out, you can vote for the feature to be added and Microsoft might add it. But there's still a way to do this:

You can set up a Logic App. There's a really nice video tutorial on this here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z0sMIN4xMSY

You can set up a logic app to use a SQL database as the trigger, and then you can decide if you want to have it trigger based on something new created in a specific table or something modified in a specific table. You can then action the logic app to trigger the run of an Azure data factory pipeline. You can set the Logic App to check the table as often as you like, for example, every minute, 3 minutes or longer etc.

If you want an ADF pipeline to run every time a certain table is modified or row inserted, but the table in question is very large, you can reduce compute by creating a track changes table. Basically have another, very small table that logs changes and then use this table for the one the logic app monitors. This would make it faster and more efficient in such a case.

Give the video a watch.